# RecyclerView skipping layout

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, kotlin, android-recyclerview

When I update the profile in the app the username and the bio update perfectly but the full name doesn't appear even though they all update in the Firebase database. Also the full name disappears when I save the changes. I believe it's a linking problem but I am a beginner and don't know how to fix it. Thanks

```
private fun updateUserInfoOnly()
{
    when {
        full_name_profile_frag.text.toString() == "" -> {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Full Name is required!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
        }
        username_profile_frag.text.toString() == "" -> {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Username is required!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
        }
        bio_profile_frag.text.toString() == "" -> {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter your bio first.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
        }
        else -> {
            val usersRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("Users")

            val userMap = HashMap<String, Any>()
            userMap["full name"] = full_name_profile_frag.text.toString() // YOU CAN REMOVE .toLowerCase
            userMap["username"] = username_profile_frag.text.toString().toLowerCase()
            userMap["bio"] = bio_profile_frag.text.toString()

            usersRef.child(firebaseUser.uid).updateChildren(userMap)

            Toast.makeText(this, "Account information has been updated successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)

            val intent = Intent(this@AccountSettingsActivity, MainActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
            finish()
        }
    }

}
```

[image: profile image]

[image: profile edit image]

Errors(the app still runs):

```
E/FirebaseInstanceId: Topic sync or token retrieval failed on hard failure exceptions: AUTHENTICATION_FAILED. Won't retry the operation.

E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
```

Comment: set an adapter to your recycler view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot see anywhere in your code the initiliaztion or attachment of Adapter. This means you need to do two things:

1.Set an adapter to your RecyclerView, if not attached already

2.Check whether the data is correctly being bind with the Adapter.

Answer (score 0):

1. Checkout function named 'getItemSize'. it should return dataset.size(), not 0.
2. Check LayoutManager. Linear, Grid.. etc. if not, recyclerView cannot render view.